# Getting Clang/Cygwin up and running on CLion

Tags: c++, cygwin, clang, clion

I own CLion, I downloaded Clang from the Cygwin installer, but I can't find it. Here is a snapshot of my status. Thanks for reading.

[image]

Comment: Not that I know anything about CLion, but I don't see where it's asking for `clang`.  It looks like it's asking for `make`, `gcc`, and `g++`.  Do you have those installed?

Comment: Yes those are installed and the software reflects this now (I recognize in that picture it did not at first).

Comment: `cygcheck -l clang` should show you where it's installed.  But I still don't see how CLion and CLang are related here.  The picture doesn't clarify either.